# How many questions are there on Stack Exchange?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

- Stack Overflow, Ask D*i*fferent, Science Fiction & Fantasy
- Drupal Answers, Lin*g*uistics, Islam, Movies & TV, Drupal Answers
- MathOverflow, Tor, Soun*d* Design, Vi and Vim
- Puzzling, Emacs, Mythology & Folklo*r*e, Esperanto Language

Comment: how many questions on Stack Exchange? too many.

Comment: @micsthepick Once it's solved, I'm gonna remind you of this comment :-D

Comment: Bold would probably be better. Can't really see it as it stands. Unless the idea is for it to be hard to find, but that doesn't seem like much of a puzzle at all, just something that will artificially make it take longer to solve.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Yes, the idea is to make it just *slightly* more challenging. I didn't want the letters to immediately stand out in a very obvious way, but OTOH I know the users of this site are experienced enough to look for such things.

Comment: The experienced users are probably experienced enough. The people who like to just occasionally pop in to take a minute or so to try to figure out some of the easier puzzles ... not so much. This should perhaps be part of a broader discussion of how accessible we should try to make the site to new users / puzzlers (?) (which is not to say "make the puzzles easier", but rather "don't complicate puzzles by adding things not part of the 'core' puzzle which experienced users will find trivial and inexperienced users may find very difficult").

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The answer is:

> LOTS

this is why:

> The italicised letters are `i`, `g`, `d`, and `r`. The only word that makes sense that you can make from these letters is `grid`. This suggests we are looking for a grid
>
>  Where can we find such a grid?, at https://stackexchange.com/sites.
>  If we start drawing lines from each sites icon, the letters, `L`, `O`, `T` and `S` are spelled out
>  [image: LOTS]

Comment: See, I said your first comment was on point :-P

Comment: love this puzzle <3

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: fixing up the pics now

Comment: +1 Like the "effect" :)

Comment: @xb. the `formatting`?

Comment: this reminds me to a puzzle I wrote in a Christmas card for a girl I liked. It was never responded

Answer (score 55):

**When you single click on a stack exchange site (i.e. Stack overflow) it gives you the number of questions on that site.** [image]

**I just did this with every site and added them all up. The answer is there are 21,716,700 (approximately) questions on stack exchange**

Comment: Ummm, I'm not sure what to do with this answer. You've certainly responded to the literal question in the title, but you haven't solved the *puzzle*. Remember this is [Puzzling.se] SE, not [Meta.se] :-) Ah well, have a +1 anyway.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I thought you were just curious and didn't know which site to put it on.

Comment: If you can make this answer update dynamically, then... Cool.

Comment: It would be a lot of effort and I don't know if I could do it. It took me about two hours to count out the first one and I'd have to do it every day. If someone is willing to count for me then I will update it reguarly

Comment: While that might be a noble endeavor, it'd also be a misplaced one *here*.  (And there are certainly easier ways to get this information with less manual effort anyway, but this entire conversation is off-topic so I'll leave it at that hehe)

Comment: Your figure is wrong. I just checked and it was some hundreds more. But by the time someone reads this any number I post is also going to be wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry. It was just meant to be a rough figure

Comment: When I read the puzzle I immediately became curious about the literal answer so +1

Comment: @WilliamPennanti, seriously? He has 66.9k reputation, very unlikely to ask such question on wrong place. BTW, this made me laughing, xD.

Comment: If stack exchange has an API to retrieve this data, then getting this information on request wouldn't be too hard. However, writing some kind of web scraper would not be fun or easy.

Comment: @peaceoutside https://data.stackexchange.com/, https://api.stackexchange.com/